# How to add a text box on google maps route?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to create a a text box between the route directions like in here :

[image]

For start i was thinking to add tooltip...but i can't place them in the middle of the route like in the picture, or set it's position to be relative.

Comment: Here is my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/h54tmmcb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom overlay as described in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

The sample code snippet might be

```
function routeOverlay(point, map, content) {
  this._point = point;
  this._map = map;

  this.div_ = null;
  this._cnt = content;

  this.setMap(map);
}    
routeOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

routeOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.padding = '4px';
  div.style.zIndex = 1000;
  div.innerHTML = this._cnt;

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
}

routeOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var p = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this._point);
  this.div_.style.left = p.x + 'px';
  this.div_.style.top = p.y + 'px';
}

routeOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
}

routeOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
    // The visibility property must be a string enclosed in quotes.
    this.div_.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
};

routeOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
    this.div_.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
};
```

Later in you code you should create this overlay. For example:

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    var ind = (response.routes[0].overview_path.length - response.routes[0].overview_path.length % 2) / 2;
    var rover = new routeOverlay(response.routes[0].overview_path[ind], map, 'Add your HTML here');
    rover.show();
} else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
}
```

I have modified your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h54tmmcb/14/

[image]

You should create corresponding styles and corresponding content for the overlay.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Xomena - Thank you So very much, i spent so much time looking for this feature!